# Is Enterprise Library 4.1 supported for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, enterprise

I was trying to run an application locally with Enterprise Library 4.1 and do logging to the event viewer. I didn't see Windows 7 under the supported operating systems. Does anyone know of a workaround or if this will not work at all? Also does anyone know if any other logging such as email or DB through Enterprise Library is available on Windows 7?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having trouble actually installing it or using it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the enterprise library should work fine as its part of the .NET framework not the OS. Your problem is down to permissions issues.

You need admin rights to 'create' a new source in the event log. You could create a console app to do this (run it under elevated permissions) or set it up directly in the registry.

Once the source is set up you should be able to write your logs away.

P.S - You can use any of the (formatters are they called?!) in the enterprise logging block. (Database, email, text file, etc)
Its setup in the config file. you can use the tool that comes with EL to do this)

Comment: its not 'part' of the framework but runs on it - ah, you know what i mean!

Answer (score 0):

Since it works with Windows Vista, it will work with Windows 7.
Under the hood, both operating systems are version 6 and both run the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise library is built on top of .net so there should be problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise library 4.1 was released before Windows 7, that's why it does not apper listed. However it should work in Windows 7 since it works in Windows Vista.